# Cron configuration on a linux apache server

Tags: apache-2.2, cron

I have a script that I want to run everyminute. I understand how to set the timings of it, I've set it as:

```
*/5 * * * *
```

My script that I want to execute is at `/var/www/html/domain.co.uk/content/inc/download-feed/banter.php`

Would I just have my crontab entry as:

```
*/5 * * * * /var/www/html/domain.co.uk/content/inc/download-feed/banter.php
```

Or is there something else I need to add to it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your cron won't run every minute (instead it will run every five minutes).

Usually, the system does not know what to do with a .php-file. So you have to use the php-interpreter and the file as argument for it:

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php -f /var/www/html/footy-feed.co.uk/content/inc/download-feed/banter.php
```

or if you want to run it every minute:

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/php -f /var/www/html/footy-feed.co.uk/content/inc/download-feed/banter.php
```

Please note: the path "/usr/local/bin/" can be different on your system.

Comment: Thank you very much! And yeah I realised after I typed /5 after the first 'every' by accident :)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need the full command, so you are basically missing the `php` interpreter in the code code you posted. Replace

```
/var/www/html/domain.co.uk/content/inc/download-feed/banter.php
```

with

```
/usr/local/bin/php -f \
     /var/www/html/domain.co.uk/content/inc/download-feed/banter.php
```

If your `php` executable live somewhere else, you'll need to adjust `/usr/local/bin/php`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends whether you have the PHP commandline interpreter installed, and whether the code inside your PHP script will just run by itself.

If it's just a piece of PHP you'd normally run from a web browser, it might not work. What's inside it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to process it with PHP, you better run it with:

```
*/5 * * * * php /var/www/html/domain.co.uk/content/inc/download-feed/banter.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have executable rights on the script file.
Make sure you don't edit the /etc/crontab, but use `crontab -e` so the config will be saved.